# How align bottom legend vertically Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

How align bottom legend vertically Chart.js ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ4fe.png)

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/doughnut.html

I need to align this code according to the image
I tried using 'options.legend.orientation: 'vertical' but I was unsuccessful
please help me to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

*Unluckily it isn't a provided property for* **legend**.

I took a look around chart.js and aligning legend items in column is only possible by positioning them to the left or right of the pie chart.

You'll need to create an [HTML Legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/html.html), which is customizable with HTML as the name suggests.

(For some reason, the code editor on the linked page doesn't update the element itself, but editing it with Chrome's web tools did the trick, you'll surely have no problems by integrating it into your js code.)

You just need `flex-direction: column`, and obviously position it accordingly, here is on the top by default.

[image: Example]